# What does this F symbol means in blueprints?

Tags: metallurgy, technical-drawing, drawings

What does this F (similar to mathematical function symbol) means in blueprints?

Year of blueprint 40s.

[image]

Comment: Please edit your question and add some context: country, industry, what the drawing is of, year, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it means finishing the surface. The finish symbol indicates the surface must be machined and finished. [source Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Engineering_drawing_abbreviations_and_symbols)

The tick line in the middle indicates the direction of the machining!